# How would one return the students that are below the average in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

For my assignment, we have to return the count of students that are below the average of the average where students are in section_id 86 and the grade_type_code is 'FI' I feel like I have it structured right because I'm able to return all the results just I can not figure out how to have them be less than or below what the average is. Here is what I have thanks!

EDIT: Have to use subqueries to achieve this goal.

```
SELECT COUNT(g.student_id) BELOW_AVERAGE
FROM grade g
WHERE g.section_id= 86
  AND g.grade_type_code = 'FI'
HAVING AVG(numeric_grade) = (SELECT AVG(below_avg)
                             FROM
                                 (SELECT AVG(g.numeric_grade) below_avg
                                  FROM grade g
                                  WHERE g.section_id = 86
                                    AND g.grade_type_code = 'FI'))
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've quite got the right answer but I'm having difficulty interpreting the question as you've said the "average of the average" and that doesn't make sense as once you have the first average you have a single value so the second average will be the same value (and if your teacher is expecting you to use a `HAVING` clause then that suggests something more complicated than a single average). It would help if you [edit] your question to include some sample data and the expected output so we can look at what is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AVG` as an analytic function so that you don't have to query the table twice:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT student_id ) AS number_below_average
FROM   (
  SELECT student_id,
         numeric_grade,
         AVG( numeric_grade ) OVER () as avg_numeric_grade
  FROM   grade
  WHERE  section_id = 86
  AND    grade_type_code = 'FI'
)
WHERE  numeric_grade < avg_numeric_grade
```

Or, if you must use two queries:

```sql
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT student_id ) AS number_below_average
FROM   grade
WHERE  section_id = 86
AND    grade_type_code = 'FI'
AND    numeric_grade < (
                         SELECT AVG( numeric_grade )
                         FROM   grade
                         WHERE  section_id = 86
                         AND    grade_type_code = 'FI'
                       )
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE grade ( student_id, numeric_grade, section_id, grade_type_code ) AS
SELECT  1, 10, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 11, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 12, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 13, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 14, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 15, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 16, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 17, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 18, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 19, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 20, 86, 'FI' FROM DUAL;
```

Then both queries output:

> ```
> | NUMBER_BELOW_AVERAGE |
> | -------------------: |
> |                    5 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8b136bd87077c50ce99fcb54d6f8df34)*

Comment: Would this count as a subquery sorry should have specified in the question that we are supposed to use subqueries for it?

Comment: THANK YOU so much. I'm going to look at it a little more so I understand it more cause the way my teacher had it explained is we needed to select statements and a having so I'm glad that that's not quite the case.